# Delete or edit particluar row in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var orderItems = [];
function GeneratedItemsTable() {
    if (orderItems.length > 0) {
        var $table = $('<table/>');
        $table.append('<thead><tr><th>Item</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Rate</th><th>Total</th></tr></thead>');
        var $tbody = $('<tbody/>');

        $.each(orderItems, function (i, val) {
            var $row = $('<tr/>');
            $row.append($('<td/>').html(val.ItemName));
            $row.append($('<td/>').html(val.Quantity));
            $row.append($('<td/>').html(val.Rate));
            $row.append($('<td/>').html(val.TotalAmount));
            $tbody.append($row);
            });

        $table.append($tbody);
        $('#orderItems').html($table);
        }
   }
```

I am able to store item in jquery array but I need to edit and delete a particular row having records.

Comment: I guess you will also need _delete_ and _edit_ buttons in your markup...

Comment: ya but it how to add give ideas

Comment: please somebody help me

Comment: `$row.append($('<td/>').html("myButtonHere"));`

Comment: I can assign itemid of using button

Comment: Instead of banging on jQuery for this, use an HTML templating solution. There are fine libraries available that are much better suited for generation of complex HTML than jQuery. Try [handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/), for example.